# Hot corners for mouse only

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad, dashboard

When I work with a mouse I want to use hot corners. When I work with the Trackpad, I don't. Is there an option for this? The hot corners should only work if I used my mouse to  activate it.
I'm not optimistic, but I can't be the only one who wants it to work like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot differentiate what kind of mouse/input device triggers hot corners. To the computer, a pointing device (mouse, trackball, trackpad, etc.) is a pointing device and all give input the same way so there's no way for it to differentiate *what* is actually moving the mouse. Hardware settings for each different device (such as tracking speed for a mouse vs a trackpad) are a different story.